# What should app do with the http get response until mongoose query returns collection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

My Node.JS app executes query on mongo database via mongoose model in the http GET route handler.

```
var users;
var usersArray;

router.get('/', function(req, res) {

     userModel.find().exec(function(err, userDocs) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                userArray   = _.toArray(userDocks);
                users       = userDocs;
            }
        });

        res.render('users', { users: {  length: usersArray.length, users: users }
    });
});
```

Mongoose query returns JS promise. What is common scenario of handling this time lag ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should handle the outcome based on the callback result from the mongoose query. This ensures you return the correct response status based on the outcome.

Also in Node.js it is best to `return` before responding to the client such as:

`return res.status(200).send()`.

`return` guarantees that execution in the current context will stop and return the result of the statement following the `return`.Even though we aren't doing anything with the result of `return` it guarantees that once we respond to the user, we don't continue executing within that context. This will prevent the code from attempting to respond twice which will result in an exception.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {

     userModel.find().exec(function(err, userDocs) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return res.status(400).json(err)
            } 

            return res.render('users', { 
              users: {  
                length: _.toArray(userDocs).length, 
                users: tournamentDocs
              }
            });
        });


    });
});
```

Comment: Should I return status code 200 and return data at the same time ? Or res.render(...) takes over responsibility for proper status code response ?

Comment: @MatkoKlaic There is no need to do `res.status(200).render()`. When doing `res.render()` you're telling the Express view engine to compile the template along with any data and send it back to the client with a Status Code of 200.

Comment: is it correct to pass userDocs to view engine, considering that 'typeof userDocs' returns 'object', or should _.toArray(userDocs) be passed  ?

Comment: That's a matter of preference on how you want to handle the data. I would just return `userDocs` and work with that data in the template instead of transforming it in the `res.render()` statement.

Comment: Is it possible to work with userDocs in the template without transforming it to array before ? How can I do that ?

Comment: @MatkoKlaic yes, also to note when doing `typeof userDocs` and userDocs is an array, `object` will be returned as the type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103218/discussion-between-matko-klaic-and-peteb).